# Fast lookup for dictionary vector to a given vector. High dimensions

Tags: python, algorithm, math, vector

I'm looking for an answer that scales, but for my specific purpose, I have a 48th dimension vector.  This could be represented as an array of 48 integers all between 0 and 255.

I have a large dictionary of these vectors, approximately 25 thousand of them.

I need to be able to take a vector that may or may not be in my database, and quickly find which vector from the database is closest.  By closest, I mean in terms of traditional distance formula.

My code will end up in python but this is more a general question.

Brute Force is too slow.  I need a near dictionary speed lookup.  Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another technique that will prove useful is locality sensitive hashing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing

Its not clear from your question whether you need -exact- nearest neighbors. If you are happy with returning a vector that is approximately the nearest neighbor, there are faster solutions. See here (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/)

Comment: LSH seems to be best for me so far.

http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/ has been a great resource.  The 2006 paper on the algorithm has been the most helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest implementing a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) on which you can perform [Nearest neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree#Nearest_neighbor_search).  The worst case search time for N points in k dimensions is `O(k.N^(1-1/k))` so it should scale sublinearly in N.

If I have time I will come back to this answer and provide a less terse explanation that Wikipedia's.

Since you're working in python this Scipy cookbook entry on [kdtrees](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/KDTree)  should help.

Comment: Effectively quite terse, but at least the pointer seems spot on!

Comment: thanks for this btw.  I did do a lot of looking into this and while kdtrees are pretty cool and I learned a lot, the LSH method mentioned below seems to be the most applicable solution due to the high dimensionality of my problem.